# Sometimes server connect failed via loadbalance

Tags: haproxy, sticky-session

My server is load balanced to the backend server via gcp https lb and the backend server uses pm2 start -i options different ports and distribute them to those nodes using haproxy.

[connection log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxnUP.png)
Log taken from server using code.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.debug("connection!", socket.id);
}
```

Once every two times, the server connection fails.

Below is Log through haproxy -d.

[fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf2uJ.png)

[success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6msm2.png)

this log is success after failure

```
00000041:http-in.clireq[000a:ffffffff]: GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=rf3JvyUz2KCKV4KDAABS HTTP/1.1
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: User-Agent: websocket-sharp/1.0
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Host: mydomain.com
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Upgrade: websocket
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Sec-WebSocket-Key: 9JCkV46YNC66nIUaZQZl9w==
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 1210ae7f3bb6e56c817e7f5ad30e1d24/17748396103009389644
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Connection: Upgrade
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Via: 1.1 google
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: X-Forwarded-For: source ip, dest ip
00000041:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: X-Forwarded-Proto: https
00000041:websockets.srvrep[000a:000b]: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
00000041:websockets.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Connection: close
00000041:websockets.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Content-type: text/html
00000041:websockets.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Content-Length: 18
00000041:websockets.srvcls[000a:adfd]
00000041:websockets.clicls[adfd:adfd]
00000041:websockets.closed[adfd:adfd]
00000042:http-in.accept(0007)=000a from [130.211.3.23:53189] ALPN=<none>
00000042:http-in.clireq[000a:ffffffff]: GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xmZEqtHokEmBfs2QAABT HTTP/1.1
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: User-Agent: websocket-sharp/1.0
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Host: mydomain.com
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Upgrade: websocket
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Sec-WebSocket-Key: 8PKkFxEv3c3KqIUW8dQbLA==
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: X-Cloud-Trace-Context: de0fa56d1689317bb9212879da8edfcb/11012650454108009103
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Connection: Upgrade
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Via: 1.1 google
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: X-Forwarded-For: source ip, dest ip
00000042:http-in.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: X-Forwarded-Proto: https
00000042:websockets.srvrep[000a:000b]: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
00000042:websockets.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Upgrade: websocket
00000042:websockets.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Connection: Upgrade
00000042:websockets.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Sec-WebSocket-Accept: tW86o/zu95tHQayPP7IlGNXi96s=
```

There is no difference, but two results. i don't know why 400 bad request

haproxy.cfg

```
global
  maxconn 4096

defaults
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option redispatch
  option forwardfor

  timeout connect 5s
  timeout queue 5s
  timeout client 50s
  timeout server 50s

frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  default_backend servers

  # Any URL beginning with socket.io will be flagged as 'is_websocket'
  acl is_websocket path_beg /socket.io
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws

  # The connection to use if 'is_websocket' is flagged
  use_backend websockets if is_websocket

backend servers
  server server1 10.168.0.50:80
#  server server2 [Address]:[Port]

backend websockets
  balance source
  option http-server-close
  option forceclose

  cookie io prefix indirect nocache # using the `io` cookie set upon handshake

  server ws-server1 10.168.0.50:5000 weight 1 maxconn 1024 cookie ws-server1 check
  server ws-server2 10.168.0.50:5001 weight 1 maxconn 1024 cookie ws-server2 check
  #server ws-server3 10.168.0.50:5002 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

i use cookie SRVNAME insert options and server name SA, SB

but socket.io document read change cookie io prefix indirect nocache and server name ws-server1, ws-server2

My Tested:

client used long polling and websocket

testClient give option {transports: ['websocket']} always success.. but real client not use only websocket options

I don't know why it fails.

If only use ws-server1 the connection will always succeed. but ws-server2 use sometime connection failed. I guess sticky session problem. I try haproxy.cfg add cookie option but The problem is not solved.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please include code and configurations in your question, not, as pictures. Pictures may not render readably on some devices or for some users and it's not possible to copy your settings into an. environment for someone who would like to help you.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts okay i try Improve